# How to Indexing my *-ros-pkg Repository for Documentation Generation

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have create a wiki page for my ros package,but it shows that 'groovy: Cannot load information on name: wlkeyctrl, distro: groovy, which means that it is not yet in our index. Please see this page for information on how to submit your repository to our index.'

Someone tell me that my repo must have a branch named groovy,unless my documentation will not be generated,is that true? Maybe the branch should be named groovy-devel?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66393/how-to-indexing-my-*-ros-pkg-repository-for-documentation-generation/) by [wunailiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5302/wunailiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is explained rather well on the ROS wiki: [ros.org/wiki/Get Involved](http://ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved#Indexing_Your_.2A-ros-pkg_Repository_for_Documentation_Generation).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wunailiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5302/wunailiang/) on 2013-07-05**:
Thanks,I have fixed it. I create a branch named groovy and then it works.